# Awk script to concatenate two column and look for concatenated values in another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

Need your help in solving this puzzle. Any kind of help will be appreciated and link for any documents to read and learn and to deal with such scenarios would be helpful

Concatenate column1 and column2 of file 1. Then check for the concatenated value in Column1 of File2. If found extract the corresponding value of column2 and column3 of File2, Again concatenate column1 and column2 of File2. Now look for this concatenated value in File1 and if found

For example - concatenate column1(262881626) and column2(10) of File1. Then look for this concatenated(26288162610) value in column1 of File2 and extract corresponding column2 and column3 value of File2.
Now again concatenate column1 and column2 of File2 and look for this concatenated(2628816261050) value in File1 and multiply exchange rate(2) fetched by concatenated value(26288162610) with taxable value(65) which corresponding to 2628816261050 of File1. Store the result of multiplcation value in column4(AD) of File1 only

File1

```
    Bill Doc     LineNo     Taxablevalue     AD
 262881626         10        245
 262881627         10        32
 262881628         20        456
 262881629         30         0
 262881630         40         45
2628816261050      11        65
2628816271060      12        34
2628816282070      13        45
2628816293080      14        0
2628816304090      15
```

File2

```
Bill.Doc     Item     Exch.Rate     
26288162610     50     2    
26288162710     60     1    
26288162820     70     45
26288162930     80     1    
26288163040     90     5
```

Output File

```
 Bill Doc        LineNo  Taxablevalue   AD
262881626        10       245
262881627        10       32
262881628        20       456
262881629        30       0
262881630        40            
2628816261050     11      65            130
2628816271060     12      34            34
2628816282070     13      45            180
2628816293080     14      0              0
2628816304090     15
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Kindly paste your code in the question. So that people can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Though your output is not clear, could you please try following and let me know of this helps you.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$NF;next} {print $0,$1 in a?"|" a[$1]*$NF:""}' OFS=""   File2 File1
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F"|" '                         ##Setting field separator as |(pipe) here.
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition here FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first file named File2 is being read.
  a[$1$2]=$NF;                      ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1$2(first and second field of current line) and value if last field.
  next}                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
{                                   ##Statements from here will be executed when only 2nd Input_file named File1 is being read.
  print $0,$1 in a?"|" a[$1]*$NF:"" ##Printing $0(current line) and then checking if $1 of current line is present in array a is yes then print a value * $NF else print NULL.
}
' OFS=""   File2 File1              ##Setting OFS to NULL here and mentioning both the Input_file(s) name here.
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, will you ever tell me reason of down vote??? I never get a reason for down vote :(

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13..Will execute and let you know..just want to know
statement "DOWN VOTER, will you ever tell me reason of down vote???" are you posting this to me..as i don't understand it

Comment: @as7951, nope that was not to you, that was whoever down voted my answer.

Comment: Hi Ravinder..in your code..not able to see where we are mutiplying column3 value of File1 with echange rate(column3) of File2

Comment: @as7951, `a[$1]*$NF` is the one where I am multiplying it. Let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Hi Ravinder...no its not producing desired output..can we discuss on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168084/discussion-between-as7951-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: here i need to store the multiplication result in column3 or column4 of File1

Comment: @as7951, please post proper samples in your post with code tags.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13..here...NR{a[$1$2]=$NF;next}..i believe we are referring $1$2 for file2 ...and here "{print $0,$1 in a?"|" a[$1]*$NF:""}"..
what are $0,$1 and again $1 pointing to

Comment: RavinderSingh13...please check my edited sample...instead of pipe..i have put space for clear visibility

Comment: @as7951, I think output is coming like that only, you could change from `OFS="|"` to `OFS="\t"` in case you need output separator as tab.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13..can you please explain code once...please...here...NR{a[$1$2]=$NF;next}..i believe we are referring $1$2 for file2 ...and here "{print $0,$1 in a?"|" a[$1]*$NF:""}".. what are $0,$1 and again $1 pointing to

Comment: @as7951, check my edit now, added explanation too in code now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13..please correct me if im wrong..in this statement {a[$1$2]=$NF;next}"..$1$2 are from file2 and in this statement.."print $0,$1 in a?"|" a[$1]*$NF:"...$0 and $1 are from file1..also cant see where we are storing result of multiplcation value

Comment: @as7951, sorry I give up now on your question. Please post more accurate samples and post more accurate details in your post and do let us know on same. I am not at all getting your question now.